# Select minimum value in columns after comparing each column to an input in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, input, compare, multiple-columns

I have the following table:

### Qual | C1  |  C2  |  C3  |  C4  |

### 50   | 0.2 | 0.5  |  0.9 |  1.2 |

### 100  | 0.3 | 0.7  | 1.1  |  1.7 |

I have an inputX1 (for example 50) and another inputX2 (= 0.7) and I am going to compare inputX2 to each column of the row which has Qual=50. So first we get:

### Qual | C1  |  C2  |  C3  |  C4  |

### 50   | 0.2 | 0.5  |  0.9 |  1.2 |

and I want to get at the end "C2" returned, after comparing inputX2=0.7 to each column of this row because 0.7 is > 0.5 and 0.2 however it is less than 0.9 and 1.2 so it should go to the closest smaller value which is 0.5 of column C2. Is there any possible way to do this? Rebuilding the database schema is sort of not an option.Please help me guys. Thanks

Comment: Well, the obvious first question is: What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebuild the database schema.

If that is not possible, you have to manually compare all columns with a [CASE expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN C4 < 0.7 THEN 'C4'
            WHEN C3 < 0.7 THEN 'C3'
            WHEN C2 < 0.7 THEN 'C2'
            WHEN C1 < 0.7 THEN 'C1'
            ELSE               '???'
       END AS ClosestSmallerColumn
FROM MyTable
WHERE Qual = 50
```

Comment: Thank you so much [CL](http://stackoverflow.com/users/11654/cl), it worked!!! I was not aware of the SELECT CASE WHEN. Thanks man

Comment: I forgot to ask but is there any way to compare these columns with a variable, like WHEN C4 < variable (simple variable or a result of another select query)? Sorry for asking a lot and Thank you again.

Comment: Whatever expression you use for that must be written four times.

Comment: Of course, but how to do it by using a variable instead of 0.7 (a variable which is the result of another query for example)?

Comment: That depends on what programming language and database driver you are using, and is a different question.